# Get the old DataContext value in UWP FrameworkElement during a DataContextChanged event

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, datacontext

The Windows Universal Platform is very similar to WPF in a lot of ways but also very different. In WPF, during a DataContextChanged event I could get the old value of the data context from `DataContextChangedEventArgs.OldValue` and the new value from `DataContextChangedEventArgs.NewValue`. In UWP, there's only `NewValue`. How can I get the old value during a `DataContextChanged` event, e.g. to remove event handler registrations from the old `DataContext` value in cases where it was an implementer of `INotifyPropertyChanged` ? I'm writing a custom control (yes, definitely needs to be custom) and I need to ensure my addition and removals of internal event handlers for this control are symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

You're right! The `EventArgs` for a `DataContextChanged` event doesn't provide a property from which we can obtain the old `DataContext` value.

But since you are creating a custom control, I think that a clean option could be to register a custom dependency property on your custom control, whose sole purpose would be to store the Old `DataContext` value, updating whenever a `DataContextChanged` event occurred.

So I started by defining a UserControl called `CustomUserControl`:

```
    public sealed partial class CustomUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public CustomUserControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty OldDataContextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "OldDataContext",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(CustomUserControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(null)
            );

        public object OldDataContext
        {
            get
            {
                return GetValue(OldDataContextProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(OldDataContextProperty, value);
            }
        }

        private void RootObject_DataContextChanged(FrameworkElement sender, 
     DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Old Data Context: " + OldDataContext);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("New Data Context: " + DataContext);


            OldDataContext = args.NewValue;
        }
    }
```

Whenever a `DataContextChanged` event occurs, we start by analyzing the type of the object set as the Custom Control's Old/New `DataContext`, by simply accessing the custom dependency property, `OldDataContextProperty`,  via the `OldDataContext` property.

The layout of the user control is rather simple, composed of a single `ComboBox` (could be anything else), which exposes the `DataContextChanged` event, whose event handler was defined above:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="UserControlForStackOverflow.CustomUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UserControlForStackOverflow"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <ComboBox x:Name="RootObject" DataContextChanged="RootObject_DataContextChanged" />
</UserControl>
```

In the layout of the MainPage, I instantiated this custom user control:

```
<Page
    x:Class="UserControlForStackOverflow.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UserControlForStackOverflow"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <local:CustomUserControl x:Name="CustomControl" />
</Page>
```

In the code-behind, I've initialized two types of Lists variables, one of type `string` and another of type `int`, to understand if the `OldDataContextProperty` dependency property was working as expected.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" };
        List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

        CustomControl.DataContext = list1;
        CustomControl.DataContext = list2;

    }
}
```

The result was the pretended:

> **Old Data Context:**
>
> **New Data Context:** System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
>
> **Old Data Context:** System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
>
> **New Data Context:** System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

When we first provoke a DataContextChanged event, OldDataContextProperty holds the default value, which is null (value specified in the `PropertyMetaData` constructor), while the current `DataContext` property is set to the first List collection.

When we change `DataContext` of the Custom Control to hold the second list, we can see that the `OldDataContextProperty` still has reference to the first object set as the control's `DataContext` , and will hold reference to it,  until the execution reaches the end of the `RootObject_DataContextChanged` EventHandler where the `OldDataContextProperty` will be set to current `DataContext` value.
You simply have to perform your desired operations before this update.

Comment: I tried this suggestion, and curiously, when I bind OldDataContext to DataContext so that I can intercept changes for both, the OldDataContext change occurs ** BEFORE ** DataContext

Comment: You should not require any binding imo for this new dependency property. Simpy track your DataContextChanged event, and only change your OldDataContext Dependency Property to the new value after you have performed your desired operations. It's rather simple, but effective.

Comment: Updated answer.